# Do U-Turn and Volt Switch have the same battle effect as Baton Pass?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-fifth-generation

I know that Baton Pass can pass almost all status conditions to the next Pokemon that switches in.

But how about U-Turn and Volt Switch? Both also switch out to another Pokemon after attacking, but are they also passing status conditions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Baton Pass and U-Turn/Volt Switch are fundamentally different, despite being similar.

U-Turn and Volt Switch simply force the user to switch out after dealing damage, even if the user should be locked in due to the effects of moves and abilities like Mean Look, Ingrain, Magma Storm, and Arena Trap. This means that a Pokémon switching out after using U-Turn will be hit by Pursuit with doubled power, and a Pokémon switching in will have no volatile statuses like Attack or Defense changes, confusion, being targeted by Lock-On, and the above mentioned trapping moves (Bulbapedia on [volatile statuses](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Status_condition#Volatile_status) and [volatile effects](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Status_condition#Volatile_battle_status)).

On the other hand, Baton Pass does not count as a switch, so it will not trigger Pursuit's effect, and does keep volatile effects on the Pokémon being switched in (not infatuation, as it's a condition between two Pokémon, not just on one). Like U-Turn and Volt Switch, it allows the user to switch out of trapping moves and effects, and those effects are not carried to the next Pokémon.

**TL;DR: U-Turn and Volt Switch are exactly like switching, Baton Pass is not**

Comment: I'm not sure that the part with pursuit dealing double dmg is true. Gotta test that one later. Nice answer tho.

Comment: @YUNOWORK I'm usually fairly confident in my Pokémon knowledge, but I made sure to double check. Bulbapedia mentions "If the foe Pokémon uses Pursuit on the same turn U-turn is used, Pursuit will deal normal damage if the foe is faster, or double damage if the foe is slower than the user.".

Comment: Little Bonus, if you want to have fun with Baton Pass, pick a Smeargle, make him learn sleep power or hpynose, minmize, draco dance and baton bass. Make the ennemy asleep, buff minimize 3 times up to 6, then draco dance and baton pass to your physical damage dealer, and everything become easy as pie :)

Answer (score 1):

U-Turn and Volt Switch only deal damage and switch out the user. They have no other effects.

Baton Pass also does not pass along status conditions (which means stuff like Sleep, Poison, Confusion, etc). Baton Pass only passes stat changes and other effects like Aqua Ring or being affected by Leech Seed.

Comment: Leech seed is not affected by Baton Pass at all, I believe.

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole Do you have a source? Everything I can find says otherwise.

Comment: I however have only played up to gen 3, so, it may be something in there. I'm just going to see if it does.

Comment: Ah, I think I was the one who switched out, not the opponent. Sorry for that.

Comment: @CaelanO'Toole If you leech seed the opponent and you switch out, the leech seed effect stays. If the opponent switches out, it's removed. However if the opponent used baton pass instead, the leech seed effect would stay and the incoming pokemon's health would still be sapped.